# Test fails due to react-native-permissions

Tags: reactjs, testing, permissions, native

**Test fails due to react-native-permissions**

**Output:**

```
react-native-permissions: NativeModule.RNPermissions is null. To fix this issue try these steps:
• If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run pod install in the ios directory and then clean, rebuild and re-run the app. You may also need to re-open Xcode to get the new pods.
• If you are getting this error while unit testing you need to mock the native module. You can use this to get started: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions/blob/master/mock.js
If none of these fix the issue, please open an issue on the Github repository: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-qrcode-scanner/node_modules/react-native-permissions/lib/commonjs/index.ts:6:9)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-qrcode-scanner/index.js:19:1)
```

**Plateform:**
*both ios and android*

before installation of `react-native-qrcode-scanner` and `react-native-permissions` all tests were ok and working perfect

here is my output attached the error I am facing

I have also mocked `react-native-permissions` in **jest.setup.js** file in root dir of project as shown below , still its not working

```
jest.mock('react-native-permissions', () =>
  require('react-native-permissions/mock'),
);
```

**at time of installation i ignored ios configrations required for this pakage because i am working on ubuntu for android only**

shall be thankfull for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found 2 ways to get rid of issue**

1.mock `react-native-qrcode-scanner` inside the test file , this is solution for single file as shown below
write mock of `react-native-qrcode-scanner` on top of test file after imports

```
jest.mock('react-native-qrcode-scanner', () => jest.fn());
```

2. mock `react-native-qrcode-scanner` inside the **jest.setup.js** file in root dir of project, this is solution for all tests files as shown below

write mock of `react-native-qrcode-scanner` inside **jest.setup.js** file in root dir as shown below

```
jest.mock(
  'react-native-qrcode-scanner/node_modules/react-native-permissions',
  () => require('react-native-permissions/mock'),
);
```